# How do I call ::CreateProcess in c++ to launch a Windows executable?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Looking for an example that:

1. Launches an EXE
2. Waits for the EXE to finish.
3. Properly closes all the handles when the executable finishes.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Something like this:

```
STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess(path, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

Comment: The WaitForSingleObject line should be ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE) (without the '&')

Comment: Why use :: to specify global namespace on WaitForSingleObject but not on the other API calls?

Comment: You should close the thread handle immediately, if you're not going to use it. Not a big problem here, though.

Comment: Why should I close it immediately? It doesn't save any resources

Comment: You're missing a ; after the WaitForSingleObject() call.

Comment: what about for .msi files? how do I execute it using CreateProcess()?

Comment: @noyruto88 if you want to "run" a .msi file, you would open it with the "msiexec" program. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/command-line-options. Pass "msiexec.exe" as the path, and command line parameters as "cmd"

Comment: Alternatively, use ShellExecute, if you want to act like the user had double clicked the .msi

Comment: How did you initialize that cmd variable?

Answer (score 25):

There is an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512(VS.85).aspx

Just replace the `argv[1]` with your constant or variable containing the program.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you application is a Windows GUI application then using the code below to do the waiting is not ideal as messages for your application will not be getting processing. To the user it will look like your application has hung.

```
WaitForSingleObject(&processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE)
```

Something like the ***untested*** code below might be better as it will keep processing the windows message queue and your application will remain responsive:

```
//-- wait for the process to finish
while (true)
{
  //-- see if the task has terminated
  DWORD dwExitCode = WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 0);

  if (   (dwExitCode == WAIT_FAILED   )
      || (dwExitCode == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
      || (dwExitCode == WAIT_ABANDONED) )
  {
    DWORD dwExitCode;

    //-- get the process exit code
    GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, &dwExitCode);

    //-- the task has ended so close the handle
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);

    //-- save the exit code
    lExitCode = dwExitCode;

    return;
  }
  else
  {
    //-- see if there are any message that need to be processed
    while (PeekMessage(&message.msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
    {
      if (message.msg.message == WM_QUIT)
      {
        return;
      }

      //-- process the message queue
      if (GetMessage(&message.msg, 0, 0, 0))
      {
        //-- process the message
        TranslateMessage(&pMessage->msg);
        DispatchMessage(&pMessage->msg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not how you combine a message loop and a wait. Use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects( QS_ALLEVENTS ); [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242(VS.85).aspx]

Answer (score 9):

Here is a new example that works on windows 10. When using the windows10 sdk you have to use CreateProcessW instead. This example is commented and hopefully self explanatory.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class process
{
public:

    static PROCESS_INFORMATION launchProcess(std::string app, std::string arg)
    {

        // Prepare handles.
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; // The function returns this
        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        //Prepare CreateProcess args
        std::wstring app_w;
        widen(app, app_w);

        std::wstring arg_w;
        widen(arg, arg_w);

        std::wstring input = app_w + L" " + arg_w;
        wchar_t* arg_concat = const_cast<wchar_t*>( input.c_str() );
        const wchar_t* app_const = app_w.c_str();

        // Start the child process.
        if( !CreateProcessW(
            app_const,      // app path
            arg_concat,     // Command line (needs to include app path as first argument. args seperated by whitepace)
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
            &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
        {
            printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
            throw std::exception("Could not create child process");
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[          ] Successfully launched child process" << std::endl;
        }

        // Return process handle
        return pi;
    }

    static bool checkIfProcessIsActive(PROCESS_INFORMATION pi)
    {
        // Check if handle is closed
            if ( pi.hProcess == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Process handle is closed or invalid (%d).\n", GetLastError());
                return FALSE;
            }

        // If handle open, check if process is active
        DWORD lpExitCode = 0;
        if( GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &lpExitCode) == 0)
        {
            printf( "Cannot return exit code (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
            throw std::exception("Cannot return exit code");
        }
        else
        {
            if (lpExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    static bool stopProcess( PROCESS_INFORMATION &pi)
    {
        // Check if handle is invalid or has allready been closed
            if ( pi.hProcess == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Process handle invalid. Possibly allready been closed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
                return 0;
            }

        // Terminate Process
            if( !TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess,1))
            {
                printf( "ExitProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }

        // Wait until child process exits.
            if( WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE ) == WAIT_FAILED)
            {
                printf( "Wait for exit process failed(%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }

        // Close process and thread handles.
            if( !CloseHandle( pi.hProcess ))
            {
                printf( "Cannot close process handle(%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pi.hProcess = NULL;
            }

            if( !CloseHandle( pi.hThread ))
            {
                printf( "Cannot close thread handle (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                 pi.hProcess = NULL;
            }
            return 1;
    }

    // helper to widen a narrow UTF8 string in Win32
    static const wchar_t* widen(const std::string& narrow, std::wstring& wide)
    {
        size_t length = narrow.size();

        if (length > 0)
        {
            wide.resize(length);
            length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, narrow.c_str(), (int)length, (wchar_t*)wide.c_str(), (int)length);
            wide.resize(length);
        }
        else
        {
            wide.clear();
        }

        return wide.c_str();
    }


};//class process
#endif //win32
```

Comment: `std::copy()` is the wrong way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. That will work without data loss only for ASCII data. For non-ASCII data, you need to *convert* the data using `MultiByteToWideChar()` or other similar function/library. `const_cast<wchar_t*>(input.c_str())` is also wrong to use. Use `&input[0]` instead, or `input.data()` in C++17.

Answer (score 8):

if your exe happens to be a console app, you might be interested in reading the stdout and stderr -- for that, I'll humbly refer you to this example:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q190351

It's a bit of a mouthful of code, but I've used variations of this code to spawn and read.

Answer (score 8):

On a semi-related note, if you want to start a process that has more privileges than your current process (say, launching an admin app, which requires Administrator rights, from the main app running as a normal user), you can't do so using CreateProcess() on Vista since it won't trigger the UAC dialog (assuming it is enabled). The UAC dialog is triggered when using ShellExecute(), though.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is the most complete?
http://goffconcepts.com/techarticles/createprocess.html

Comment: Nice. A link only answer to 404 File not found.

Comment: @Eric Duminil Still valid in 2022.

Comment: @o_oTurtle More like "valid again". The link has been updated 3 days after my comment. The next time it will go down, pcunite might not notice or still be around to update it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that using `WaitForSingleObject` can get you into trouble in this scenario. The following is snipped from a tip on my website:

> The problem arises because your application has a window but isn't pumping messages. If the spawned application invokes SendMessage with one of the broadcast targets (*HWND_BROADCAST* or *HWND_TOPMOST*), then the SendMessage won't return to the new application until all applications have handled the message - but your app can't handle the message because it isn't pumping messages.... so the new app locks up, so your wait never succeeds.... DEADLOCK.

If you have absolute control over the spawned application, then there are measures you can take, such as using SendMessageTimeout rather than SendMessage (e.g. for DDE initiations, if anybody is still using that). But there are situations which cause implicit SendMessage broadcasts over which you have no control, such as using the SetSysColors API for instance.

The only safe ways round this are:

1. split off the Wait into a separate thread, or
2. use a timeout on the Wait and use PeekMessage in your Wait loop to ensure that you pump messages, or
3. use the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` API.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <Windows.h>
void my_cmd()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    // CMD command here
    char arg[] = "cmd.exe /c E:/Softwares/program.exe";
    // Convert char string to required LPWSTR string
    wchar_t text[500];
    mbstowcs(text, arg, strlen(arg) + 1);
    LPWSTR command = text;
    // Run process
    CreateProcess (NULL, command, NULL, NULL, 0, 
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```

This works fine for me. No popup windows and cmd command runs as expected. Just needed to convert the CHAR pointer into WCHAR pointer and add extra "cmd.exe /c" before every command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for `CreateProcessA`

```
STARTUPINFOW initInfo = { 0 };
initInfo.cb = sizeof(initInfo);
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = { 0 };

CreateProcessA(PATH_FOR_EXE, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOA)&initInfo, &procInfo);
```