# C++ Start another program and exit

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program where it starts another .exe and itself just closes after the other program has started.

I currently have the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main( )
{
    std::system( "checkpoint.exe" );
}
```

I can get `checkpoint.exe` to start, but the starter program itself doesn't close until `checkpoint.exe` closes. How would I get around this?

Comment: you need to start a separate process which won't block your program execution, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067789/how-to-create-a-process-in-c-on-windows)

Comment: Some systems maintain a process hierarchy. Each process (except for the first) is a child of anther process. You are trying to destroy that kind of hierarchy. Some systems have the ability to create detached processes. It is likely then that you will have to use an operating system specific call to create such a process.

Comment: @Axalo: seems like he's using windows though, so no fork :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you appear to be using Windows, you can use [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo;
LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo;

memset(&lpStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(lpStartupInfo));
memset(&lpProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(lpProcessInfo));

CreateProcess("checkpoint.exe"
              NULL, NULL, NULL,
              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
              lpStartupInfo,
              lpProcessInfo
             )
```

Comment: MSDN also has some good [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about the various process creation flags :)

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer has some bugs. You have to initialize `STARTUPINFO` and `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structs, not `LPSTARTUPINFO` or `LPPROCESS_INFORMATION`. The latter are just pointers to the structs.

Here's a working solution:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
    
int main( )
{    
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
    
    ZeroMemory( &StartupInfo, sizeof( StartupInfo ) );
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof( lpStartupInfo );
    ZeroMemory( &ProcessInfo, sizeof( ProcessInfo ) );
    
    CreateProcess( "Program.exe",
                   NULL, NULL, NULL,
                   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                   &StartupInfo,
                   &ProcessInfo
                   );
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What bugs are you talking about? Could you describe them in your answer?