# How can I open a help file (chm or so) from my GUI developed in VC++ 2008?

Tags: c++, process, chm, winhelp

I'm trying to add some help to my GUI developed in VC++ 2008. I want to compile a chm file, or a hlp file that can be accessed from my menu. Anyone can give me any idea about how to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you are asking about creating a .CHM, or simply opening an already created one (or both?). Perhaps you could clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\HTMLHelp** , create an entry
named **help.chm**
value **C:\path to\help file.chm**

Then to open the chm at a particular topic call

```
 HtmlHelp(m_hWnd, "Help.chm", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just ShellExecute the .chm file.  That will open it.

```
ShellExecute( hWnd, _T( "open" ), _T( "help.chm" ), NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question earlier.

For opening the Help file, you can use WinHelp

Some Links:

[First (PDF)](http://www.smountain.com/resource/CPPWinHelp.pdf)
[Second](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=287)
[Third](http://simplesamples.info/MFC/HTMLHelp.php)

There are some issues with WinHelp in Windows Vista and Win2K8, For details on how to deal with them, [Look here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917607)

Comment: I know how to create this files, I want to know how to link them to my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using managed C++:

In the namespace

```
System.Windows.Forms
```

you can find the class **Help** with static methods **ShowHelp, ShopHelpIndex**

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.aspx

If you are using unmanaged C++ (WIN32 api):

You can just launch the *.chm file. Example how to do it you can find here: [How do I call ::CreateProcess in c++ to launch a Windows executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531/how-do-i-call-createprocess-in-c-to-launch-a-windows-executable) . Or here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/newbiespawn.aspx