# WinAPI function to start help file

Tags: c++, winapi, chm

when you open help in e.g. Windows Notepad (Help->Help Topics) no child process is started (such as hh.exe), which IMO means there is a WinAPI function called to do the job.

I searched  MSDN for a while but came up with nothing.

what is this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help? [How can I open a help file (chm or so) from my GUI developed in VC++ 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226876/how-can-i-open-a-help-file-chm-or-so-from-my-gui-developed-in-vc-2008)

There are several useful solutions in that discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `HtmlHelp`

Comment: ... or if you are starting a Windows help file use the WinHelp function.