# How to open a process in C?

Tags: c, process

How do I open a process that isn't connected with my program in C?
for example:
if the user enter the following input:
start C:\Windows\calc.exe

then the calculator will open.
thanks.

Comment: do you want to open the process (using OpenProcess) or do you want to start it (CreateProcess)?

Comment: sample: http://nikisurf.blogspot.com/2011/10/c-program-to-open-calculator.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call ::CreateProcess in c++ to launch a Windows executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531/how-do-i-call-createprocess-in-c-to-launch-a-windows-executable)

Answer (score 1):

[Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) are not known by the *C* standard. You can code in standard *C* for a system without processes (e.g. bare metal, or MS-DOS).

On Posix compliant systems, you could use [popen(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) (with `fscanf` and `pclose`).

You may also use the [system(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) function.

Your operating system may have a non-Posix interface. Please dive into your system's developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [createProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows.Also look into this [thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/19762/) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531/how-do-i-call-createprocess-in-c-to-launch-a-windows-executable) previously asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `system()` function. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)