# How do I call the unicode function CreateProcessW in c++ to launch a Windows executable?

Tags: c++, unicode, createprocess

There is an example of how to call CreateProcess on stack exchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531/how-do-i-call-createprocess-in-c-to-launch-a-windows-executable%20here), however this seems to be no longer supported on Windows 10, and you must use the unicode version CreateProcessW.

In a similar vein to the ASCI version, I am looking for an example that:

1. Launches an EXE
2. Waits for the EXE to finish.
3. Properly closes all the handles when the executable finishes.

Comment: I've answered my own question, as I spent a while working out how to do this and have since decided to use an external library (Poco) to do instead. As far as I know there is no example on how to use CreateProcessW, so I have posted one here. I also didn't want the time I spent writing this to be a waste.

Comment: The thing is that `CreateProcess` is one of a very large number of functions with `W` versions. How to use wide strings isn't specific to any of these; you can learn that separately and apply it to any one of these functions, including `CreateProcess`.

Comment: That's true. You can close this question if you think it is unsuitable for stack exchange. To be honest I just didn't want the time I spent writing the code to be a waste.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing new about Windows 10 in this respect. Your question is really about Unicode versus ANSI, and Visual Studio's new default settings which use Unicode.

`CreateProcess` is a macro, it is defined as

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateProcess  CreateProcessW
#else
#define CreateProcess  CreateProcessA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

In addition `STARTUPINFO` is a macro for `STARTUPINFOA` and `STARTUPINFOW`

`CreateProcessA` uses ANSI char strings `char*` and `STARTUPINFOA`

`CreateProcessW` uses Unicode wide char strings `wchar_t*` and `STARTUPINFOW`

If you insist on using ANSI (not recommended) then go to Project Settings -> Character Set and disable Unicode.

If you insist on using ANSI version with Unicode settings (still not recommended), you need

```
//Using ANSI when UNICODE is defined (not recommended):
STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
std::string path = "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe \"c:\\test\\_text.txt\"";

//if not using C++11 or later, force a zero at the end 
//to make sure path is null-ternminated
path.push_back(0);

if(CreateProcessA(NULL, &path[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE); 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Above code will work as long as the directory names are ANSI compatible. But the recommended version is:

```
//recommended:
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    std::wstring path = L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe \"c:\\test\\_text.txt\"";

    //if not using C++11 or later, force a zero at the end 
    //to make sure path is null-ternminated
    path.push_back(0);

    if(CreateProcess(0, &path[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}
```

Also, don't cast from constant string to string as follows:

```
wchar_t* arg_concat = const_cast<wchar_t*>( input.c_str() );
```

The second argument in `CreateProcess` should be `wchar_t*` because the process may modify the command line.

Comment: Note that `&path[0]` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated until C++11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is it enough to write `path.push_back(0)` to assure the string is null-terminated?

Answer (score 1):

This example is commented and hopefully self explanatory.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class process
{
public:

    static PROCESS_INFORMATION launchProcess(std::string app, std::string arg)
    {

        // Prepare handles.
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; // The function returns this
        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        //Prepare CreateProcess args
        std::wstring app_w(app.length(), L' '); // Make room for characters
        std::copy(app.begin(), app.end(), app_w.begin()); // Copy string to wstring.

        std::wstring arg_w(arg.length(), L' '); // Make room for characters
        std::copy(arg.begin(), arg.end(), arg_w.begin()); // Copy string to wstring.

        std::wstring input = app_w + L" " + arg_w;
        wchar_t* arg_concat = const_cast<wchar_t*>( input.c_str() );
        const wchar_t* app_const = app_w.c_str();

        // Start the child process.
        if( !CreateProcessW(
            app_const,      // app path
            arg_concat,     // Command line (needs to include app path as first argument. args seperated by whitepace)
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
            &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
        {
            printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
            throw std::exception("Could not create child process");
        }
        else
        {
            // Return process handle
            return pi;
        }


    }

    static bool checkIfProcessIsActive(PROCESS_INFORMATION pi)
    {
        // Check if handle is closed
            if ( pi.hProcess == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Process handle is closed or invalid (%d).\n");
                return FALSE;
            }

        // If handle open, check if process is active
        DWORD lpExitCode = 0;
        if( GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &lpExitCode) == 0)
        {
            printf( "Cannot return exit code (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
            throw std::exception("Cannot return exit code");
        }
        else
        {
            if (lpExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    static bool stopProcess( PROCESS_INFORMATION &pi)
    {
        // Check if handle is invalid or has allready been closed
            if ( pi.hProcess == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Process handle invalid. Possibly allready been closed (%d).\n");
                return 0;
            }

        // Terminate Process
            if( !TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess,1))
            {
                printf( "ExitProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }

        // Wait until child process exits.
            if( WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE ) == WAIT_FAILED)
            {
                printf( "Wait for exit process failed(%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }

        // Close process and thread handles.
            if( !CloseHandle( pi.hProcess ))
            {
                printf( "Cannot close process handle(%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pi.hProcess = NULL;
            }

            if( !CloseHandle( pi.hThread ))
            {
                printf( "Cannot close thread handle (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                 pi.hProcess = NULL;
            }
            return 1;
    }
};//class process
#endif //win32
```

Comment: `stdio.h` is a deprecated C-compatibility header. Use `cstdio` in C++ instead. Additionally, you really should use the `nullptr` type instead of `NULL`, whereever possible. Additionally use the types `true` and `false` instead of C-style defines for them.

Comment: @tambre: it's best to pass the WinAPI appropriate types. They're typically mapped to the ones you'd think, but it's not guaranteed.