# How can I check if CreateProcess is working or running?

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I use `CreateProcess` to start a .exe of mine. I want to know if everything worked fine or if it encouter errors when I tried to start this .exe.

From what I can tell, I need to use `GetLastError()`, but I tried to simulate an error in the process path but it return the same last error code.

So I want to catch if `CreateProcess` is successfull or not and if the process is done. What should I do to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call ::CreateProcess in c++ to launch a Windows executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531/how-do-i-call-createprocess-in-c-to-launch-a-windows-executable)

Comment: Check the return value of CreateProcess. True indicates success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the information you are looking for is spelled out in the documentation for [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).
>
> Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization. If a required DLL cannot be located or fails to initialize, the process is terminated. To get the termination status of a process, call [GetExitCodeProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess).

If you need to wait for the target process to terminate, call [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) on the process handle returned in the [PROCESS_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information) filled out by the call to `CreateProcess`.

Since you control the target process, you are free to choose any scheme that allows you to determine success or failure from the process' exit code. You can call `GetExitCodeProcess` at any time after the process' handle transitioned to the signaled state, and before you call `CloseHandle` on it.

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches I can think of:

## #1 - Enumeration

You can enumarate the processes and check if the `PID` is in the list. Check out [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx)

## #2 - Checking Exit Codes

You can use [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(VS.85).aspx). It will return `STILL_ACTIVE` (259) if the process is still running

## #3 - Process Handles

[WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) uses a Process handle with the SYNCHRONIZE access right and returns 0 if the process is not running.

*Note: You should not specify INFINITE for the dwMilliseconds parameter because the function would not return until the process state became signaled(process is terminated).*

Comment: The correct answer is of course to check the value returned by CreateProcess.

Comment: Some processes return a 0 exit code even though they encounter an ‚error.‘, which results in the process not starting. I don’t think that’s the correct answer but it may work. An example I can think of is starting MEMU from shell, which always result in return code 0. **If the binary is programmed poorly you don’t get any useful return codes!**

Comment: The OP is starting *their own program*. They have all the tools at their disposal to signal success/failure through their process' exit code.